# Adding custom commands to the publish process in a .net core web api app

Tags: c#, .net, makefile, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm publishing a `.net core` web API app in a macOS and Ubuntu environments. Other than the .net packages which are published smoothly in both cases I'm also trying to publish a custom dynamic library. The library is defined as `Copy Always` and it is indeed copied to the output folder as needed. But before copying it I would like to recompile it by running a custom `make` command using a pre-existing `Makefile`. The `Makefile` is generic and works in both environments, creating a 'shared library' in Ubuntu and a 'dylib' file in macOS.

I edited the pre-build custom commands in visual studio and I'm able to recompile the library with every build but I can't replicate this behavior to the `dotnet publish` command. Is there any way to add custom commands to the `dotnet publish` process?

Comment: Have you looked into Cake (https://cakebuild.net/) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute .bat file at end of VS2017 Asp.Net Core publish action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030112/execute-bat-file-at-end-of-vs2017-asp-net-core-publish-action)